# Android TV - How to implement endless RecyclerView like with Leanback HorizontalGridView

Tags: android, pagination, android-tv, television, leanback

I couldn't figure out a solution to implement pagination in my Android TV application. I'm using Leanback support library - `HorizontalGridView` for listing items. `HorizontalGridView` is extended from `RecyclerView` but its layout manager (`android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager`) didn't implemented `findLastVisibleItemPosition()` method.

How can I implement pagination for the `HorizontalGridView`. Is there any way to listen to the event that `HorizontalGridView` reached the end of its content (or even if we use `ListRowPresenter`)?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem! Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [Endless Scrolling with AdapterViews and RecyclerView](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) documentation. Based from this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-the-RecyclerView#implementing-endless-scrolling), to implement fetching more data and appending to the end of the list as the user scrolls towards the bottom, use the `addOnScrollListener()` from the `RecyclerView` and add an `onLoadMore` method leveraging the [`EndlessScrollViewScrollListener`](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView#implementing-with-recyclerview) document in the guide.

Comment: Thanks for you comment, but this documentation use LinearLayoutManager#findLastVisibleItemPosition() method, which one didn't implemented in android.support.v17.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager in my case

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same problem and I think we can use the `OnChildViewHolderSelectedListener`:

```
recyclerView.addOnChildViewHolderSelectedListener(
    object : OnChildViewHolderSelectedListener() {
        override fun onChildViewHolderSelected(
            parent: RecyclerView,
            child: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
            position: Int,
            subposition: Int
        ) {
            super.onChildViewHolderSelected(parent, child, position, subposition)
            if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                parent.layoutManager?.let { layoutManager ->
                    Logger.d(
                        "Selected position $position of ${layoutManager.itemCount - 1}"
                    )
                    if (position > layoutManager.itemCount - 1 - THRESHOLD) {
                        Logger.d("Should load more items")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)

companion object {
    private const val THRESHOLD = 3
}
```